# delete checked table rows with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, delete-row, checked

I have checked through numerous questions to find the solution. I know I'm close, but I'm still not getting anything happening with my deleteData.php after confirming to delete.

### Status:

Testing the array provides successful result.
**Example:** I checked rows 1, 2 & 31...then press #btn_del.
First, I get the confirm "Are you sure...?"
Next, I see the correct alert(array) 1,2,31
The next step...ajax is supposed to be sending this array data to deleteData.php for processing.

### script

```
$('a#btn_del').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); 
    page    = $(this).attr("href");
    ids     = new Array()
    a       = 0;

    $(".chk:checked").each(function(){
       ids[a] = $(this).val();
       a++;
})   
      //  alert(ids);

if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete these courses?")) {

     $.ajax({
            url         :   'deleteData.php',
            data        :   ids,
            type        :   "POST",
            //dataType  :   'json',
            success     :   function(res) {
                             if ( res == 1 ) {
                                 $(".chk:checked").each(function() {
                                     $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                                  }) // end if then remove table row
                               } // end success response function
            } // end ajax
     }) // end confirmed
}
return false;
}); // end button click function
}); // end doc ready
```

### deleteData.php

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');                             // Connect to the database

   $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
    or die ('Error connecting to MySQL server.'.$dbc);

        foreach     ($_POST['ids'] 
        as          $id) {
            $sql = "DELETE FROM unit_genData 
                    WHERE unit_id='" . $id . "'";
            $result = mysqli_query($sql) 
                    or die(mysqli_error($dbc)); 

            }                                           // end echo result count


mysqli_close($dbc);                                     // close MySQL

echo json_encode(1);    
?>
```

### Edited:

Updated GET to POST.
Updated data: 'ids' to data: ids

### Tested:

a) In php...echo $_POST['ids']; 
NO RESULT
b) In js...commented out the if(confirm...
NO RESULT

### Status:

Looks like the AJAX isn't firing (so to speak)

Comment: `data        :   "ids",` should be  `data        :   ids,`

Comment: Also remove the spaces `unit_id=' " . $id . " ' "` - `unit_id='" . $id . "' "` - which would translate to `space ID space` - I saw that happen yesterday.

Comment: `or die(mysqli_error().$sql);` should be `or die(mysqli_error($dbc));`

Comment: @briansol updated data - same result

Comment: @Fred-ii- removed spaces & updated die ... same result

Comment: Additional errors may lie in your form then. That's if you are using a form, which I take it you are.

Comment: Another thing. Why do you have 2x `.parent()` in `$(this).parent().parent().remove();`? You should post your form also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the 2x parent is referring to removing the `<tr>` for each of the rows with a checked checkbox. `parentx1 = <td> parentx2 = <tr>`...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would use POST instead of GET for a delete.

Then you need to send the correct data to your php script. What you have now is just a string, no key-value pairs which is what you expect at the backend.

The easiest way to send your data would be to use something like (assuming you have a form):

```
data: $('form').serialize(),
```

but you can also send an array like the one you are building:

```
data: ids,
```

The advantage of the first method is that values automatically get escaped / encoded (wouldn't make a difference with just integers obviously...).

At the backend you would need to prevent the sql injection problem you have now. You can do that using a prepared statement with bound parameters or in the case of numeric ID's you can cast them to integers.

**Edit:** As noted in the comments by @Fred-ii-, additional spaces in a string will cause your condition to fail. I would recommend a prepared statement but if you decide to cast to int and use that, just remove the quotes.

Also note that the procedural `mysqli_*` functions take the database link as the first parameter, that applies both to the query and to the error handling.

Comment: This `unit_id=' " . $id . " '` could also be a factor; the spaces, as per [`my comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681467/delete-checked-table-rows-with-ajax#comment41961895_26681467)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, a prepared statement would definitely be the way to go but an integer (without quotes obviously) would also work.

Comment: There was a question posted yesterday where the OP was using the very same syntax. Turns out that it was the spaces in the quotes causing the problem.

Comment: No doubt. My comment was in regards to a *probable* contributing factor. Plus, `mysqli_error()` should be `mysqli_error($dbc)`

Comment: ...we'll get 'er done ;) and what rhymes with "done"? Plus one ;)

Comment: @jeroen thanks for this info. I've updated to POST. Still no change. I'm not 100% about using $('form').serialize(). I didn't want to bother with the checkall checkbox included in the form/table. I've got a feeling it has something to do with the POST/GET...should there be a `if(isset($_POST))` in the php? Would this be affected by the fact that I'm using a `<a href>` image button instead of a `<input type="button">`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've continued to try to get this to work. I've checked the form and the table. All seem to be working fine for my create/submit/INSERT INTO read and edit/UPDATE. My DELETE query works fine in MySQL. I'm at a loss as to why the Ajax just doesn't seem to be working at all. Would appreciate any further assistance you could share